# 複数のVagrantfileでセットアップ内容をプロジェクトごとに変えるには

Tags: vagrant

今まではVagrantを1つだけ使っていたのですが、同じOSで別セットアップのものが必要になりました。
別ディレクトリーで新しいvagrantfileを作成し、vagrant upをすると、2台目の内容がなぜか1台目と2台目の両方に適応されてしまいます。

【ホスト構成】
localnginx.dev  192.168.33.10
localapache.dev  192.168.33.11

【1台目のvagrantfile】

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  
  config.vm.define :"localnginx.dev" do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.8"
    web_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    web_config.vm.synced_folder "../home/sample1", "/home/sample1/htdocs", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=644"] }

    web_config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
      ansible.inventory_path = "hosts/development"
      ansible.limit = "all"
    end

    web_config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "localnginx.dev"
      vb.memory = "2048"
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end
  end
end
```

【2台目のvagrantfile】

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  
  config.vm.define :"localapache.dev" do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6.8"
    web_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
    web_config.vm.synced_folder "../home/sample2", "/home/sample2/htdocs", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=644"] }

    web_config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
      ansible.inventory_path = "hosts/development"
      ansible.limit = "all"
    end

    web_config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "localapache.dev"
      vb.memory = "2048"
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end
  end
end
```

【前提】

- Vagrantfileやマウントさせるディレクトリー、ansible-playbookの中身は別物です。
- 同じOS(CentOS 6.8)でも、プロジェクトごとに全く異なったセットアップの環境を作りたいです。

【問題点】

- 2台目synced_folderが1台目にも適応されてしまう
- 2台目のansible-playbookに登録されているタスクが1台目にも適応されてしまう

こちらの原因をしばらく探してみたのですが、なかなか見当たらないので、
アドバイス頂けると大変助かります。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `vagrantfile`と小文字で書かれていますが、実際のファイルの頭文字は大文字になっていますか？

Comment: 実際にはVagrantfileです。失礼しました。

Answer (score 0):

原因は前回の vagrant 設定をディレクトリーごとコピーしていて、その中の `.vagrant` ディレクトリーもコピーされていたことが原因でした。

---

*この投稿は @stlab さんが質問文に記載した内容を元に、コミュニティwiki で個別の回答として投稿しました。*